# Using sockets to create clicks on android device (Converting from python to C)

Tags: python, c++, c, sockets

I am trying to create a socket program that communicate with client android device to simulate clicks on it, so far I managed to set up and run the TCP server code successfully on Python using the code below.

```
import socket
import time
 
HOST = '192.168.1.243'
PORT = 4000
 
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
   s.bind((HOST, PORT))
   s.listen()
   conn, addr = s.accept()
   while True:
       time.sleep(1)
       conn.sendall(b'a 925 1725\n')  //Click 1
       time.sleep(1)
       conn.sendall(b'a 220 2100\n')  //Click 2
```

After some research, I am able to produce the C code for TCP server to bind host and port, listen for clients and accept clients.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>                                                                                                       
#define PORT 4000
                                                                                                                        
int main(int argc, char const*argv[])
{
            int createsocket, phone_socket;
            struct sockaddr_in server;//Declare structure to connect to a remote server
                int opt = 1;
                int addrlen = sizeof(server);
                char buffer[1024] = {0};
                ssize_t sendto(int createsocket, const void *buf, size_t len, int flags, const struct 
                sockaddr *dest_addr, socklen_t addrlen);
                                                                                                                                        
                createsocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);    //To create socket                                                   
                if (createsocket == -1){                                                                                                      
                printf("Error creating socket");                                                                                  
                }
                                                                                                                                         
                 //Assign structure                                                                                                      
                 server.sin_family = AF_INET;
                 server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("10.10.10.10"); //Assign host
                 server.sin_port = htons( PORT ); //Assign port

                 //Bind host and phone
                 if (bind(createsocket, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server))<0){
                        printf("Bind error\n");
                        return 1;
                        }
                else
                        printf("Bind Connected\n");

                //Ready to receive connections                                                                                          
                 if (listen(createsocket, 5) < 0){
                        printf("Listening error\n");
                        return 1;
                        }
                else
                        printf("Listening\n");

                //Connection received, pending accept
            if((phone_socket = accept(createsocket, (struct sockaddr *)&server,(socklen_t*)&addrlen)< 0){
                     printf("Failed to accept\n");
                     return 1;
                     }
                 else
                     printf("Accepted device\n");

                  while(1){
                     sleep(1);  //One second delay
                     printf("click\n");  //Supposed click command
                     }
}
```

Anybody knows how to convert the python line `conn.sendall(b'a 925 1725\n')` for clicking into C?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: 925 1725 are the coordinates of the client android phone

Comment: Why not using ADB interface, instead of creating own protocol etc.? Commands are quite easy if you are connected to the shell e.g. adb shell input tap x y

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to change into C from Python or something else? I might be able to help with a bit more explanation of what your goal is other than clicking into C.